# How can I connect my application to a SQL Server that is on another computer?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have created a Winforms app to insert data into database.That works fine with my local `Database.mdf`. But I need to connect my application to SQL Server 2014 that is installed on other computer/domain.

My logon screen for SQL Server looks like this:

[image: logon screen SQL Server 2014]

My code for insert data into database is:

```
 private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string connetionString = null;

    //connetionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\NIKOPOL\Desktop\Barcode ver1\Barcode ver1\Database2.mdf";
    connectionString = @"Data Source=10.89.149.12,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=KontrolniCOC; User ID=Boris;Password=entermypassword";
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cnn;

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into...";
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

So I guess that all I need is that I change my connection string to:

```
 connetionString = @"Data Source=10.89.149.12,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=KontrolniCOC; User ID=Boris;Password=entermypassword";
```

But it throws an exception 0x80131904 a network-related...

[image]

My app will be run on a computer that has no SQL Server installed.

Comment: Go to sql server configuration manager and enable TCP/IP for network protocols. After that you can try.

Comment: Ok after I done ping askra01apcp200 (they told me that is the name of sql server, and after doing telnet everything was fine so 1433 works)  I've got: ping askra01apcp200.fiatauto.adfa.local [10.89.149.12]. So what should my connetionString look like?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhaVt.png** hope this helps, I have edited the active code in the office for you.**

Comment: Tnx a lot.will try this